# How to change schema of tables used in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have procedure dbo.GetData:

```
Create procedure dbo.GetData
As
Begin
Select * from dbo.tblName
End
```

And I also created a schema [ABC], table ABC.tblName

So, I would like to change schema [dbo] of table in procedure dbo.GetData into [ABC] by using another stored procedure. 
And, the result is:

```
Create procedure dbo.GetData
As
Begin
Select * from [ABC].tblName
End
```

How can I do it?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I would like use procedure dbo.GetData to get data of table [ABC].tblName in schema [ABC]. And don't want to create procedure ABC.GetData any more.

Comment: I'm afraid that makes even less sense!

Comment: You tagged this as MySQL and SQ Server. Which is it?

Comment: Removed `mysql` tag as this is clearly for SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but I think you simply want to change the code being executed in the stored procedure. If so, a simple `ALTER PROCEDURE` would do the trick to change the code, but not the name:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetData
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [ABC].tblName
END
```

Full syntax of `[ALTER PROCEDURE]` [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762.aspx) (for SQL Server)

If this is not what you're after, please clarify the question.

Update:

The only real solution I see is that you script out your procs, and then use a text-editor to replace the `dbo.` values with `[ABC].` values.

I just attempted to try and do this through updating the system tables, but in SQL Server 2012 (which I use), it simply gets far too complex for that.

Comment: You're right. But for example, I have 100 procedure and every procedure have 1000 code lines. so, what's solution to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this may help you!

```
ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER OldSchemaName.ObjectName
```